# java find a specific line in a file based on the first word

Tags: java

I have a file that I am importing and what I want do is ask for the user's input and use that as the basis for finding the right line to examine.  I have it set up like this:

```
     public class ReadLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
         File fileNames = new File("file.txt");
     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileNames);
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int count = 0;
    int lineNumber = 1;

    System.out.print("Please enter a name to look up: ");
    String newName = in.next();

    while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
          if(scnr.equals(newName))
          {
              String line = scnr.nextLine();
              System.out.print(line);
          }
      } 
}
```

Right now, I am just trying to get it to print out to see that I have captured it, but that's not working.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Also, if it matters, I can't use try and catch or arrays.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use [`String.startsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

Comment: i think you want to use the `sncr.findInLine` API, not `equals`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!  Both of those were great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cache the line in a local variable so you can print it out later. Something like this should do the trick:

```
while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
    String temp = scnr.nextLine(); //Cache variable
    if (temp.startsWith(newName)){ //Check if it matches
        System.out.println(temp); //Print if match
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something in the lines of:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a name to look up: ");
String name = in.next();

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLineS(new File("file.txt").toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Optional<String> firstResult = lines.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith(name)).findFirst();

if (firstResult.isPresent) {
    System.out.print("Line: " + firstResult.get());
} else {
    System.out.print("Nothing found");
}
```